# python understanding : lists

Tags: python, list

I am trying to understand use of `:`. I have below example code. I am not getting what the last line is doing. Please explain. Also please share how or when to use `:`

```
listoflists = []
list = []
for i in range(0,10):
    list.append(i)
    if len(list)>3:
        list.remove(list[0])
        listoflists.append((list, list[0]))
print (listoflists)

print (listoflists[:][0][1])#print y values only for the first batch, : for all batches 
print (listoflists[0][1])
print(listoflists[:])
```

Comment: `[:]` is the nothing index. That is to say that `[1,2,3,4,5][:] == [1,2,3,4,5]`

Comment: @kpie Wouldn't that make it the "*everything* index"? Have a link to the "nothing index" terminology?

Comment: @kpie could you show when `[:]`  could be used to do something useful?

Comment: It's the equivalent of saying `a[0:len(a)]` which is equivalent to just saying `a` I really can't think of any case where it is helpful other than as a placeholder during debug.